# Can a PSObject have properties that are PSObjects?

Tags: c#, powershell, expandoobject, psobject

I have a C# Cmdlet that interacts with a REST service, deserializing JSON as dynamic objects (`ExpandoObject`). When an expando is passed to `WriteObject` it gets written to the pipeline as a dictionary so I am converting it to a `PSObject` like so in order to make its properties accessible by the likes of `Select-Object`:

```
protected void WriteDynamicObject(dynamic o)
{
    var psObject = ConvertToPSObject(o);
    WriteObject(psObject);
}

private static PSObject ConvertToPSObject(dynamic o)
{
    var d = o as IDictionary<string, object>;
    Debug.Assert(d != null);

    var record = new PSObject();
    foreach (var kvp in d)
    {
        // if the value is itself an expando, convert it recursively
        var value = kvp.Value is ExpandoObject ? ConvertToPSObject(kvp.Value) : kvp.Value;

        record.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty(kvp.Key, value));
    }

    return record;
}
```

This works swimmingly for all of the dynamic object's properties except for properties that are themselves a complex type. The above code will recursively convert non-scalar child objects into PSObject instances. As an example the projectTeam property of this JSON result is converted to a PSOBject:

```
{
   "kind": "storage#bucketAccessControl",
   "role": "OWNER",
   "projectTeam": {
    "projectNumber": "930617506804",
    "team": "owners"
   },
   "etag": "CAE="
  }
```

When I try to select the `projectTeam` property from the pipeline I get a string representation and cannot select the properties of that sub object:

```
projectTeam
-----------
@{projectNumber=930617506804; team=owners}
@{projectNumber=930617506804; team=editors}
@{projectNumber=930617506804; team=viewers}
```

I guess I was expecting to be able to select or otherwise navigate the object hierarchy. Are `PSObjects` intended to be essentially a flat set of name value pairs or can they represent an object hierarchy? If so, how does one represent a nested object such that its properties are selectable or is it necessary to flatten the object hierarchy?

Comment: Is `projectTeam`'s value really a string? It looks like a hashtable. Have you stepped through the code to see if the `projectTeam` key's value is actually being interpreted as an `ExpandoObject`? Maybe the inner properties are plain hashtables, and so `kvp.Value is ExpandoObject` will evaluate to `false` and then the recursion will never happen.

Comment: @briantist I have stepped through and projectTeam is indeed being converted to a PSObject. That syntax in the object dump is the ToString of PSObject.

Comment: When you say you try to select the property from the pipeline, you mean in Powershell? Can you post that code?